# A Database Error Occurred (SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This database has worked fine for two years, now it's getting the following error? Can someone explain this issue and suggest a way to resolve this?

> Error Number: 1104
>
> The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Code:

```
select 
    salary_tb.*, order_tb.order_no, 
    daily_target_tb.customer as customer_name, 
    jobs_tb.job as job_name 
from 
    salary_tb 
left join 
    order_tb on salary_tb.order_id = order_tb.id 
left join 
    daily_target_tb on order_tb.id = daily_target_tb.order_id 
left join 
    jobs_tb on salary_tb.job_id = jobs_tb.id 
where 
    salary_tb.id > 0 
    and salary_tb.isDeleted = 0 
    and salary_tb.employee_id = '1' 
group by 
    salary_tb.id
```

Filename: models/SalaryModel.php

Line Number: 22

Comment: it's not working either 

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by salary_tb.id' at line 18"

Comment: your code is work on workbench, its not usable in my web application

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your query is either returning huge number of rows which is more than value set for `MAX_JOIN_SIZE` configuration or your `SQL_BIG_SELECTS` is set to 0 which will not allow you to run queries which take too long to return a result. You can do one/all of the following 3 things :

1.`SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;`

2.`MAX_JOIN_SIZE= (More than the no of rows returned by the join statement)`

3. Refine your query so that it returns appropriate values within the set parameters and in less time.(Using Indexing, Returning less no. of rows).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, can you explain, how to "
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;" to my query?

Comment: This is my query

Comment: Just run it in mysql command line or in mysql workbench as you run a normal query.

Comment: I've had trouble with how to integrate it, I've added my code as an answer above, can you show it, please? 

Comment: Set this at database administrator level, If you are having admin access to database.  No need to set this configuration again and again through php.

Comment: How do I do that? I've all the privileges.

Comment: login in to mysql using mysql command line or Mysql Workbench. If you are using mysql commandline after login you should fire following query mysql> SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;  In mysqlWorkbench you can directly fire the query on any worksheet and then commit

Comment: tried that. still the same result 

Answer (score 0):

**Current Query**

```
function get_rows($where)
{
    $sql =      
    "select salary_tb.*, order_tb.order_no, daily_target_tb.customer as customer_name, jobs_tb.job as job_name
            from salary_tb
            left join order_tb on salary_tb.order_id = order_tb.id
            left join daily_target_tb on order_tb.id = daily_target_tb.order_id
            left join jobs_tb on salary_tb.job_id = jobs_tb.id
            where salary_tb.id > 0";
            
    if($where != ""){
        $sql .= $where;
    }

    
    $query =# $this->db->query('SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1'); 
            $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).